# Trying to prove that a function got no limit at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,   defined by:
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1 & y=x^{2}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
How can I show that this function got no limit at $(0,0)$?
Can I define a sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and get: $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n,(x_n)^2)=1$ so the limit is $1$, but if I will take $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,0) = 0$ ?

Is this a valid proof?
Thank you!

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a valid proof. Here are a few more details on why that's good enough:

Assume that there *is* a limit at $(0, 0)$ and call that limit $L$. Now, by the definition of limit, given an $\epsilon < 0$, there must be a $\delta < 0$ such that whenever $0<|(x, y)|<\delta$, we have $|L - f(x, y)| < \epsilon$.

Now, taking $\epsilon$ to be $1/3$, for instance, then no matter what $\delta$ we pick, there is an $n$ big enough so that both $(x_n, 0)$ and $(x_n, (x_n)^2)$ are closer than $\delta$ to the origin. But $f(x_n, 0) = 0$ and $f(x_n, (x_n)^2) = 1$, and no matter what $L$ is, those two function values can't *both* be within $1/3$ of $L$. Therefore, assuming there is a limit, we cannot find a $\delta$ small enough for $\epsilon = 1/3$, which is a contradiction. The conclusion is that there cannot be a limit.